# VS2012 remote debugging without an administrator account

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

Let me explain a little about us. We are a group of developers who have a dedicated server for our team, but it is still administered by another group that enforces organization wide policy. Their ideal scenario would be to set remote debugging up as a service and allow anyone in our group to access the debugger through our local workstations. To give our group administrator privileges on the server, is likely to be the last option.

We have looked through a list of Microsoft pages, which are listed below:

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f.aspx --

This article explains the reasoning behind why an administrator account is suggested.
-- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2008/05/15/visual-studio-remote-debugger-service-user-account-requirements.aspx --

This article points to the need of having an administrator logged into the server while another user is remotely debugging. Not an option.
-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291278(v=vs.71).aspx --

-- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2004/10/04/237519.aspx --
-- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/2cd87191-f0fb-462b-8367-c1b7e3ddf443/ --

We have firewall permissions set up where we can see the server running msvsmon. Most of what has been found, states that when the remote debugger is running as a service on the remote machine, only administrators can connect to the debugger. So far we have not found a practical solution.

Is there anyway to setup a network group that would be able to access the remote debugger, without giving the group administrator privileges? Other options?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can add the user that you want to a special group allowing Debug permissions, if you want to prevent a write access on records in production you need to configure your database to remove those privilege for that group. Btw you need to have the same pdb files that you compiled when your release was done. In that way you will be able to debug your code, other way you will be blind to see where the values come from. Is a good practice to keep the pdbs from your last release and have them accessible for your developer team.

[image]

Comment: We base our releases off of a version, so if a new individual needs to debug other than the last to deploy, they just deploy again, so that the symbols match.

Comment: that is just one thing to take care, what about the creation of the new group with special debug privileges and removing write access in production database?